# WebDav on custom port with redirect

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, webdav

Is it possible to connect to WebDav using custom port which also has redirect to https? When I remove redirect everything works.

```
DAVLockDB /var/www/DavLock
<VirtualHost *:882>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/storage
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}:444/$1 [L,R]
   
    <Directory /var/www/storage>
        Options Indexes Multivews
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Location />
         DAV On
         AuthType Digest
         AuthName "authname"
         AuthDigestProvider file
         Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you intend to use ssl using port 443 ? If yes you will need to modify the redirect rule and specify the virtual host for 443 with the webdav config.